# How to update Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a `Notification` in my android application. And this `Notification` has a progress bar.

My question is: if I update progress in the progress bar of my `Notification`, should I pass the SAME instance of `Notification` or create a new instance of `Notification`?

should I do this:

```
mNotification = new Notification(..); // create in the constructor of my activity

getNotificationManager().notify(TAG, FILE_UPLOAD_ID, mNotification);
```

or

```
getNotificationManager().notify(TAG, FILE_UPLOAD_ID, new Notification(...) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same.

> public void notify (String tag, int id, Notification notification)
>   Since: API Level 5
>
> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification
>   with the same tag and id has already been posted by your application
>   and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated
>   information. ***
>
> Parameters tag    A string identifier for this
>   notification. May be null. id     An identifier for this notification.
>   The pair (tag, id) must be unique within your application.
>   notification  A Notification object describing what to show the user.
>   Must not be null.